# Which is better and correct, 'It is not yet, or, it is yet not?'

Tags: phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

I want to know which of the two phrases is better
It is yet not
or
It is not yet

Comment: Hello Bhanu Mathur, please see this guide for how to ask a good question.https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - have you researched the answer to this? If so can you add what you found if you checked a dictionary for instance or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, mostly, but depend on context.
For example,
"It is not yet fully planned how the design will look like.", meaning that it has not been planned by this time. Here the usage of "It is yet not fully planned..." is incorrect.

Also, "yet" is used in times like,
"It is yet to be decided what the design will look like.", Meaning the decision has not been made at the time, but will be in the future.

Comment: The full statement is -The family business deals with providing advertising services and media solutions to public and private sector corporations. In terms of consumer perception and competitive durability though, it is yet not a name to reckon with.

Comment: considering the context, i feel here "yet not" is better, not that i have a strong reason to strictly say "not yet" is incorrect. If you break the sentence when reading like (It is yet)(not a name to reckon with) would make sense. If you break it that way, the meaning will be like "(Still), (it is not a thing to consider)."

Comment: glad it helped. why the downvote?